# After trying to build a package in ROS-Melodic i get the ERROR: "Could NOT find Boost"

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, ros, pcl

So I'm a bit new to working with ROS, so if I failed to include important information to solve this issue, feel free to ask.

My problem is as follows. I wanted to install and try out the package [Bezier](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/bezier), for ROS-melodic. Supposedly its plug and play, but thats not how ROS works from what I've read :D

After downloading the package and following the instructions as listed in the README, i get this error message, when trying to run catkin_make:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'bezier'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(bezier)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:48 (message):
  common is required but boost was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/c:687 (pcl_report_not_found)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:850 (find_external_library)
  bezier/CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mnn_cd/rosstuff/catkin_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mnn_cd/rosstuff/catkin_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I have searched for solutions to this problem, but either there werent any, or some that I dont understand.
Boost is installed (version 1.65.1 iirc). People said to look in the cmakeList.txt file, for how boost is referenced, but in the bezier cmakeList.txt there is no such thing.
I even added this line to the cmakelist.txt

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
```

but the Error persists.

So the Error lies in the PCL? There i found the PCLConfig.cmake file and Boost is referenced a lot. But i have no idea to begin to understand how and where there could be an issue.

Could someone please help me understand the error message, or even help me fix it?

Comment: Which PCL version are you using and how did you install it? How did you install Boost?

Comment: So the PCL Version is 1.8.1.
I never installed Boost myself, this is a work Laptop. But both Boost and PCL are in the urs folder. Does that mean they were installed manually?

Comment: Sorry i meant to write usr*

Comment: I think the likeliest problem is that your PCL version is too old to work with your Boost version. PCL 1.8.1 was released before Boost 1.65.1. I would recommend to try a newer PCL version.

Comment: I think 1.8.1 is the newest version that is compatible with Ubuntu 18.04, which is what im using (ROS - Melodic). After un- and reinstalling PCL the problem persists. Ill try to downgrade Boost to an older version. Ill update when im done!

Comment: So ive downgraded Boost to an older Version (1.54). This seems to fix this particular error message. So first of all, thank you very much!
I now have new issues, all related to PCL and VTK but i think those too are related to the age of the package i want to implement. So ill try to play with older versions of those too, to see if 'Bezier' can be built then.

If im able to make Bezier work, ill edit this issue and then close it.

Comment: Great! I also just found https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/5052 , maybe it is useful for you